# Q chaining with progress nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am having a problem with understanding how promises in chains working.
I have this code:

```
AsyncMain()
.then(function() {
    return async2();
})
.progress(function(file) {
    return asyncReadFile(file);
})
.then(function(fileData) {
    console.log(fileData); < -- -- - does not returning the file data
})
```

all asyncs returns promise.

for example

```
function async2() {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    fs.readdir(mainRoot, function(err, filesInDir) {
        files.map(function(file) {
            defer.notify(asyncReadFile(file));
        })
    });

return defer.promise;}
```

Does promises has Ids so I can to which function my promise belongs?
Does someone has article or documentation how to work with progress?
cant find about it articles

Comment: An excellent and popular article on promises generally is here: [We have a problem with promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html). Try adding a catch block to see where your promises are failing.

Comment: you never resolve nor reject the promise in async2.

Comment: I think notify can be used for progress. You can wire it up as a third param to 'then'. I have an article here where I explain chaining http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promise-chaining-explained This focuses on chaining and doesn't address progress though. It also uses $q which is an angular port of $Q, but should be similar.

Comment: In jQuery I use notify() instead of resolve() so I can use progress() instead of then()/done().

Comment: Don't try to do streaming with promises. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Q has global unhandled rejection hooks - add `process.on("unhandledRejection"` - and see where your code is failing. Progress is deprecated don't use it anyway. Q is a pretty old library btw I wouldn't use it for new code.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what will you use?

Comment: @Daffa definitely bluebird.